# cannot convert 'int (*)[4]' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'void generaMatriz(int**, int, int)'

Tags: c, funciones

He estado realizando este programa, y el único error que manda es sobre los apuntadores, de como es que estamos mandando y recibiendo las variables.

A es una matriz que se genera con números aleatorios.
La función mayorDirección devuelve una copia idéntica del dato mayor almacenado en una matriz y la posición en la que se encuentra dentro de la matriz

El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#define orden 4

int** reservaMemoria(int filas, int columnas);
void liberaMemoria(int ** A, int filas, int columnas);
void generaMatriz(int** A, int filas, int columnas);
int  mayorDireccion(int** A, int filas, int columnas, int* filasMay, int* columnasMay);
void pintaMatriz(int** A,  int filas, int columnas);


int main ()
{
    int A[orden][orden], filas, columnas, Grande, filasMay, columnasMay;
    system("color 03");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    
    printf("Ingresa el número de filas: ");
    scanf("%d", &filas);
    printf("Ingresa el número de columnas: ");
    scanf("%d", &columnas);
    
    columnasMay = columnas;
    filasMay = filas;
    
    A = reservaMemoria(filas, columnas);
    generaMatriz(A, filas,columnas);
    
    Grande = mayorDireccion(A, filas, columnas, filasMay, columnasMay);
    
    system("cls");
    printf("La matriz es:\n");
    pintaMatriz(A, filas, columnas);
    
    printf ("Y el grande de la matriz es: %d", Grande);
    system("pause");
    
    liberaMemoria(A, filas, columnas);
    return 0;
}

void generaMatriz(int** A, int filas,int columnas)
{
    int i,j;
    
    for(i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<columnas; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand()%10;
        }
    }
}

void pintaMatriz(int** A,  int filas,int columnas)
{
    int i, j;
    
    for (i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {    
        for(j=0; j<columnas; j++)
        {
            printf("[%d] [%d] = %d \n", i, j, A[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int** reservaMemoria (int filas,int columnas)
{
    int** pArreglo;
    int i;
    
    pArreglo = (int**)calloc(filas,sizeof(int*));
    
    if(pArreglo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memoria insuficiente...");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<filas; i++)
        {
            pArreglo [i] = (int*)calloc(columnas,sizeof(int));
            
            if(pArreglo[i] == NULL)
            {
                printf("Memoria insuficiente...");
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return pArreglo;
}

void liberaMemoria(int ** A, int filas, int columnas)
{
    int i;
    
    for(i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        free(A[i]);
    }
    
    free(A);
}

int mayorDireccion(int** A, int filas,int columnas, int* filasMay, int* columnasMay)
{
    int i, j;
    int may;
    
    may=A[0][0];
    *filasMay=0;
    *columnasMay=0;
    
    for(i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<columnas; j++)
        {
            if(A[i][j]<may)
            {
                may = A[i][j];
                *filasMay=i;
                *columnasMay=j;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return may;
}
```

Quisiera saber cual es la solución más óptima para seguir usando apuntadores en el algoritmo anterior. Sería de gran ayuda (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si declaramos un array tal que:

```
int A[2][2] = {{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }};
```

Nos encontraremos que todos los valores de la matriz acaban ubicados en posiciones contiguas de memoria:

```
  00   01   02   03
|  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |
```

El compilador debe conocer en todo momento las dimensiones del array para poder calcular la posición de cada elemento.

Sin embargo, un puntero doble funciona de forma diferente. En este caso, la variable almacena una dirección de memoria. Lo que vamos a encontrar en esta dirección de memoria son más direcciones de memoria. Estas últimas direcciones ya sí apuntarán a enteros. Es decir, sería algo tal que:

```
   0x00    0x01        0x100 0x101        0x200 0x201
| 0x100 | 0x200 | ... |  1  |  2  | ...  |  3  |  4  |
```

Como ves, la estructura en memoria cambia radicalmente y de ahí que el compilador te muestre un error.

La solución pasa por usar estructuras de datos compatibles. O usas arrays o usas punteros dobles. Tienes que elegir una de las dos soluciones, ya que no puedes mezclarlas.

Mi opinión personal sería usar punteros. Los arrays son estructuras con poco recorrido debido principalmente a varios factores:

- Se almacenan en la pila del programa. La pila tiene un tamaño muy limitado y, si se llena, el programa muere.
- No se puede modificar su tamaño de ninguna manera
- Al estar en la pila, debes que tener cuidado con los punteros que lo referencien. No vaya a ser que el array se destruya y los punteros se queden apuntando a memoria que ahora pertenece a otras variables